# How to provide native support for unsupported webRTC JS APIs in WebKit(WkWebview)

Tags: ios, webrtc, hybrid-mobile-app, cocoahttpserver, apprtcdemo

***Objective:***

Providing native support for the unsupported WebRTC JS APIs in WebKit and make WebRTC call through the webapp loaded in WkWebView.

***So far What I have tried:***

As of now WebRTC W3C JavaScript APIs is not supported in webkit.

There is a cross platform plugin available from [cordova](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) to support webRTC but I don't want to go cross platform way.

There is a webRTC [native framework](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios) available but I don't want to go completely native way.

So far I was able to override *navigator.getUserMedia* in JavaScript

```
navigator.getUserMedia = function(constraints, onSuccess, onError){
    myWebRTC.getUserMedia(document.getElementById('roomid').value)
}
```

and call native AppRTC SDK API to initiate the call from the native side and it works.

```
if let roomId=NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("RoomId"){
    appClient = ARDAppClient(delegate: self)
    appClient?.createLocalMediaStream()
    appClient?.connectToRoomWithId(String(roomId), options: nil)
    localVideoView?.hidden = false;
    remoteVideoView?.hidden = false;
    btnDisconnect?.hidden = false;
    webview?.hidden = true;
}
```

Here is the complete [source code](https://github.com/Duraiamuthan/WebRTCSample)

AppRTC it has its own native video view, but I want to show the video in HTML element inside the webview.

AppRTC doesn't provide a video stream as well... even if I could a way to get the stream out of it. How can I give the stream to wkwebview is a challenge because its RTC with just evaluate JavaScript I don't think its possible.

So I have integrated [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) and I am thinking of finding a way to stream from this to WkWebView.

Any insights, suggestions in achieving my objective is highly appreciated!

Comment: [Have you seen this?](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples/wiki/Developing-a-hybrid-iOS-app)

Comment: Openwebrtc is not completely supporting the WebRTC JS APIs.They're working on it. You can also give a try on **Bowser** in iTunes which is nothing but a Browser with support of WebRTC using OpenWebRTC library.But I tried to make a call by loading https://apprtc.appspot.com the call is not happening

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [plugin iosRTC](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) for iOS and crosswalk for android but we didn't found a cross platform plugin :/

Here our tutorial : https://apirtc.com/apirtc-on-cordova/

And one sample project with cordova : https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-mobile

Comment: I don't intend to do using cordova .. I want to do a just a hybrid way ! swift in native and wkwebview